# easy regex - how to select the first 6 characters of a string

Tags: regex

I have these string

```
'e600', 'ci-home' },
'e6c1', 'ci-home-alt' },
'e601', 'ci-pin' },
'e602', 'ci-comment' },
'e603', 'ci-comment-dots' }`
```

and need to **select only the first 6 characters** of each line.

Comment: To brief to post as an answer: `^.{6}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(.){6}
```

or

```
^.{6}
```

try this let me know if it works

it works by selecting from `^` start, `(.)` every single character within, `.` characters within, `{6}` 6 characters. first one group the full match
not important for your case

Comment: why the brackets?

Comment: yes that worked. is it possible to select on all lines in same expression?

Comment: what you mean (.) mean "everything" and what do you mean by  all lines in same expression can you tell me

Comment: updated answer the original answer

Comment: @vyshnavvyshu I have multiple lines and needs to select the first characters of each line. is that possible in the same expression?

Comment: @SteinTheRuler yes it's possible

Comment: @vyshnavvyshu but you don't know how?

Comment: @SteinTheRuler you can use the same code for multiple lines as well try it

Comment: @vyshnavvyshu I can't get it to work in notepad++. but.. do you know how to select everything on a line except the 6 first characters?

Comment: `(?<=^.{6}).*`  @SteinTheRuler try this. this will select everything except first 6 characters